# What does "do" mean in "What do I do"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "do" mean in "What do I do?" I think it means "What do I usually do?", but I don't know why anyone would ask what they usually do. Does it mean something else?

Comment: A third possibility (two others have been mentioned in the answers already) is this: A: Oh, no. You're doing it again! B: What? A: You do it every time. B: **What do I do?** A: You roll your eyes and snort! I hate that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Do* can occur both as an auxiliary verb and as a lexical verb. In your example, it is an auxiliary verb in the first instance and a lexical verb in the second instance. The lexical verb, I assume, presents no difficulty. It means things like *perform, execute, achieve, carry out, effect, bring to pass.*

As an auxiliary verb, *do* is used to form questions and negatives. When a question begins with a word like *what*, and that word is not the subject, auxiliary *do* (or *does* in the third person singular) is placed before the subject of the clause. This applies when the lexical verb is *do*, just as much as it does with any other lexical verb.

In a clause such as this, *do*, as ctype.h has suggested, **can** mean *should*, but it does not necessarily do so. The question could, for example, be a response, seeking clarification, to the question ‘What is your job?’

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the first *do* means *should*. Therefore, *What **do** I do?* means *What **should** I do?*. If someone asks *What do I do*? they are not asking what they *usually* do, they are asking what they *should* do.

While this usage is common in colloquial English, it should usually be avoided in formal English; it would be better to say *What **should** I do?* unless you are quoting someone.

Additionally, there is a similar question, *What do you do?*, which usually means *What job do you do?* or *Where do you work?*. This, like the other question, is also informal.

Comment: Not just that, as I have suggested in my own answer.