# Use of did and wanted in one sentence

Tags: tense

I wanted to know if we can use *did* and *wanted* in the same sentence.For example in the following sentence:

> What did he wanted to prove through the experiment?

Is this a correct sentence? It uses *did*  and *wanted* together.

Comment: What did he **want** to prove

Comment: Yes and no.  You can certainly use *to do* and *to want* in the same sentence, but you don't conjugate the verb after *to do*: What did he *want*, not What did he *wanted*.

Comment: This question is surely a duplicate.

Comment: Actually you did so in your first sentence...

Answer (score 3):

In English we can only have one tensed verb in a verb phrase. The auxiliary *DO* is always tensed. It is always either past tense or present tense.

If we use the auxiliary *DO*, the Complement verb phrase will always use a *PLAIN* form of the verb. This is the word you see in the dictionary.

- She didn't WANT  a chocolate.

Notice in the sentence above that because *did* is in the past tense, the verb *want* cannot be past tense. It is in the plain form. Notice also that the verb *want* is not present tense. The following sentence is ungrammatical:

- She didn't want**s** a chocolate. (ungrammatical).

For these reasons the Original Poster's example needs to use the verb *want* in the plain form:

> What did he want to prove through the experiment?

Comment: Tense is not a verb in English with the meaning you ascribe to it. One tenses one's muscles, one does not "tense" a verb. To try and explain to someone how action verbs are put into the simple past by saying "the auxiliary DO is always tensed" is pretty confusing.

Comment: @Lambie Altough *tense* is not yet found in most dictionaries, it is used by grammarians and in grammar books students use. A search engine will return quite a few examples including on Stack Exchange sites (ELU & GL for instance).  [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tense#Verb) has it ((grammar, transitive) To apply a tense to.) Usage often precedes dictionary entries.

Comment: @Lambie I read lots of grammar books, I can't even recall them. And the most common way they describe what a finite verb is is by saying it's "tensed". Even [TRomano](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81024/is-there-any-reason-why-we-cant-use-i-hope-you-to-buy-me-a-doll) says so. And please don't take things too literally.

Comment: @Lambie "tensed verb" is a normal way to refer to a verb that has tense in English. It's completely idiomatic and totally normal. Of course, whether it's a verb or an adjective there is up for debate ....

Comment: No, there is no debate here about verbs versus adjectives. And no, if you teach English to beginners, you don't say a tensed verb. That term would be marked as linguistics, not ELL, unless ELL pedagogy. ('orrible word). You say a verb in the present tense, a  verb in the past tense, etc.

Comment: @Lambie It's clearly explained in the answer. "It's either past tense or present tense".

Comment: @user178049 Yes, its clearly explained in my answer. For an English Language Learner.  In the OP's question, there is a mistake in the past tense. The auxiliary of action verbs is not past tense or present tense. The auxiliary of an action verb can be /have/ or /would/ also: I have painted, I would paint: neither is past or present.

Answer (score 0):

When using a verb *to do*, you must use the plain form of verb after it. And the verb *to do* is sufficient to mark the tense.

> What did he want to prove through the experiment? (*did* marks past tense).

But there is an exception for this rule. You can use *do/did* with a past tense form of verb in a [cleft-sentence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence) because the verb to do functions as a lexical verb, not as an auxiliary.

> All he did *was* eat the food.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. You can get round your cleft exception by saying that the verb *did* takes a complement with a plain form. In your cleft sentence the verb *was* is not a complement of *did*. The word *did* is part of the subject and the verb *was* is the predicator. They aren't in the same VP :) There are many sentences which can do this "That he did what he did was not surprising", for example. The second *did* is part of the subject, but *was* is the head of the predicate verb phrase.

Comment: Yes @AraucariaMan, but I think the cleft structure is a horse of a different color. And I actually tried to make my answer as simple as possible since the OP doesn't even know how the auxliary verb works. Anyway, your comment is *appreciated!* :)

Comment: I'm fine with any kind of downvote. But the OP please disregard it, I raised the most important exception here, which is in the cleft sentence.

Comment: I think someone did a driveby downvote! Everyone on the page got downvoted!!! Pity. I thought there were 4.5 good answers here :-)

Comment: Saying **did** is a verb in OP's sentence can be very confusing for a learner and is not grammatically correct.   **Do** here is an **auxiliary** (see Araucaria Man's answer).   It would be a verb in "I always do the housework at the weekend". See what Barrie England  [says about it here on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/976/2818), it's very good and clear to my point of view.

Comment: @Laure Hmm.. Why are taking it so literally? Saying *verb to do*, *verb to have*, and *verb to be* is a very common way to generalize it. And that's why **I mentioned the exception for a cleft-sentence(i.e when the verb *DO* is used as a lexical or main verb rather than an auxiliary)**

Comment: This is not talking "literally". It is important to use the words that describe a reality and used by grammar books and most language teachers, chiefly if OP is - as you mentioned - a beginner.  *Auxiliary verbs* and  *lexical verbs* are entirely different things and the difference is introduced very early when teaching EFL, as it is essential to grasp the way the English language works. You can study the language at a very high level and never hear of a cleft sentence. I doubt the page you are linking to can help OP.

Comment: @Laure But *auxiliary* is short for *auxiliary verb* in many grammars (though not all of them).  :-)

Comment: @AraucariaMan *auxiliary verb* is not *verb* ! They are different grammatical categories. *Verb* is sometimes used for *lexical verb*, never for *auxiliary*.

Comment: @Laure See page 29 here, and then pages 37-40: [A Student's Introduction to English Grammar](https://www.slideshare.net/MrMinhajahmed/a-students-introduction-to-english-grammar) Huddleston & Pullum 2005.

Comment: @Laure Or you could see here from the Internet Grammar of English published by UCL university. [This page here](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/verbs/auxil.htm)

Comment: @AraucariaMan *Helping verb* is what I use. It seems the page you're linking to  says auxiliary verbs and lexical verbs *differ*, or are we understanding it differently?

Comment: @Laure [here](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/grammar/overview.html), it's similar to SIEG. I would like to know which book that says *auxliary verb* is not a *verb*.

Comment: @user178049 Nobody says *auxiliary verb* is not a *verb*. I said "*Verb* is sometimes used for *lexical verb*, never for *auxiliary*", which replying to AraucariaMan's comment meant: *auxiliary verb* is never shortened as *verb* but as *auxiliary*. I would not object to your answer if instead of writing "when using a verb to do" you had written "when using **the** auxiliary do" (removing the **to** that marks it as a lexical verb).  I would like to know which book says an *auxiliary verb* is a *lexical verb*, which is what your answer implies, there's no "exception": they're different words.

Comment: @Laure I said I use the term [verb to do](https://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/verbtodo.html) to generalize the concept. "Verb to do" includes both auxliary and lexical verb.

Answer (score 0):

**Declarative sentence** in the simple past in English:
He **wanted to prove** something with his experiment.

**Interrogative sentence** in English:
**Did he want to prove** something with his experiment?

Interrogative pronouns follow the interrogative sentence rule:
**What did he want** to prove etc.
How did he want to prove etc.
Where did he want to prove
When did he want to prove etc.

The word **did** in the simple past and the words do/does [careful with the s in the third person] are the helping verbs used to make interrogative sentences in English. In the interrogative form, the subject and the verb are inverted.

Do you like tea?
Did you like the tea served at the party?

**This is basic English grammar.** And that is the proper terminology for explaining it in the simplest way.

Please do not edit this answer. It is structured the ***way*** I want it to be structured.

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure ... "Did he be happy?" "Did you be in when the accident happened?" "Did you had already asked him?"

Comment: Clearly, the OP does not know how to form the simple past interrogative for an action verb. And probably doesn't know how to in the present either.  Of course, one can't cover everything in the English language in every question, i.e. the verb /be/.

Answer (score -2):

You can simplify your question a lot: "Is 'he did wanted' correct?"

And the answer is "no".  In English, when you use a modal verb, only the modal verb is inflected; the main verb remains as the bare infinitive.

So "He did want" instead of "He did wanted", and "He does want" instead of "He does wants".

Read [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs) about modal verbs.

Comment: Yes, but the auxiliary  verb "do" is not a modal.

Comment: I was trying to simplify the distinction between modality and do-support and may have gone too far.

Answer (score -3):

With **did**, or **didn't**,  the main verb following it takes the present tense.

> What did he wanted to prove through the experiment?

What did he **'want'** to prove through the experiment?

Another example- "Why didn't I **get** the ice cream?"

"Oh, I didn't **know** that you didn't **get** any."

Comment: *want* is not the present tense after *to do*.

Comment: Yes... that's why I mentioned only did and did not...  I never mentioned the infinitive.

Comment: Your statement "With **did**, or **didn't**, the main verb following it takes the present tense" provides incorrect information. The main verb is not in the present tense. It is not in any tense.  It is the plain form or base infinitive.

Comment: Ok... agree.. but you should have mentioned it in your previous comment to clarify.